# Why Dialogflow doesn't work as expected for **alpha/beta** testers?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on **dialogflow** and **actions on Google** for **Google assistant integration**. I have been working on it from last few months, I created **dialogflow agent** made required changes and setting in **actions on Google** as well. I used to test each and every day after implementing new features to my app (using Webhook) and found everything well before **submitting** to **apha/beta approval**. After completing my work with the app, I just submitted it for **alpha/beta approval** to **Google** and they approved it. At this point I just sent the opt in link(provided by actions on Google for alpha users for testing purpose) to the **alpha testers**. But unfortunately nothing is working as expected. After analyzing I found that all the **parameters** are **always empty** in the **webhook request** sent from **dialogflow** and **intent** didn't match as expected. But for me (developer or owner) it works fine, I mean to say alpha/beta versions are not working. The parameters should have the values of matched **entity synonyms** that have been added/loaded to **dialogflow** dynamically via **dialogflow V2 APIs**. It is working fine with owner account or developer account, But not with alpha/beta release.

While checking via **postman** if the **entities** gets loaded to **dialogflow** or not i found **entities** were loaded successfully to dialogflow with the same **dialoflow V2 api**, But due some reasons **webhook request** always sends empty strings for parameters.

**Can any one have any idea why is this happening, And what is the solution for this issue?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. And I found that my google actions are in deploying state and I have tried to test it with an opt-in link. But After a few hours, it is deployed properly and my custom google actions worked fine. And you also need to do alpha testing enabled in your mobile from an opt-in link.

[image: see this image which includes Alpha version and its state]